# Setting dynamic position of element using Javascript instead of jQuery offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can dynamically position a div element, so that as the *user moves the mouse the element follows*, using jQuery:

```
inputFile.offset({
   top: ev.pageY - 15,
   left: ev.pageX - 160
});
```

I would prefer to not use jQuery. How would I accomplish the same using vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Define div to use then create a function for the X and Y coordinates and one for the cursor then have div follow cursor.

```js
var div = 'mydiv'; // div that will follow the mouse. Set position:absolute in CSS
var offset_X = 10; // X offset from mouse position
var offset_Y = 10; // Y offset from mouse position

function mouseX(evt) { // create function for x mouse event
  if (!evt) evt = window.event;
  if (evt.pageX) return evt.pageX;
  else if (evt.clientX) return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
  else return 0;
}

function mouseY(evt) { // create function for Y mouse event
  if (!evt) evt = window.event;
  if (evt.pageY) return evt.pageY;
  else if (evt.clientY) return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
  else return 0;
}

function follow(cursor) { //  create function for cursor
  var obj = document.getElementById(div).style;
  obj.left = (parseInt(mouseX(cursor)) + offset_X) + 'px';
  obj.top = (parseInt(mouseY(cursor)) + offset_Y) + 'px';
}
document.onmousemove = follow; // call function when user moves mouse
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"> </div>
```